# Positioning Navigation Bar buttons in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, ios7

I am using custom image for navigation bar button.In iOS 6,if we set the left bar button item with button,its x value starts from 10px. But in iOS 7,if we do the same thing,x value of button starts at 20px. Is there any way we shall make it start from 10px as the buttons appearance is not so good with that in iOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItems can be initialized using initWithCustomView: method. So you can create some custom view (in your case navigation bar button item with custom image) and initialize bar button item with that custom view. Example:

```
    CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
```

You can set any frame you want in initWithImage: method of CustomView:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 44)];

    CGRect backArrowFrame;


    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        backArrowFrame = CGRectMake(-8, 12, 12.5, 20.5);
    } else {
        backArrowFrame = CGRectMake(-2, 12, 12.5, 20.5);
    }

    UIButton *imView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:backArrowFrame];
    [imView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imView setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [imView addTarget:target action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:imView];


    return self;
}
```

In this way it is possible to change frame of UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: I know this..i didn't want to go via this way.I was expecting something like toplayoutguide which we can use to provide guiding for those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the `UIBarButtonItem` frame. Instead, subclass `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 0):

**Add button as navigation item in ios7 as below**

```
UIButton *btnAdd = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];

[btnAdd setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

[btnAdd setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnAdd addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imView];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnAdd;
```